# Storing items and groups of items

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema

Let's say I'm storing images.  I have all of the images in a database with an auto increment ID, file name, size, etc.  Now I want to be able to group the images.  For example, I want all of the pictures of nature in the "nature" group.
I have a new table called "groups".  How should I put the images in the group "nature"?  Here are a few of my thoughts:
1. Have a new table storing the image id and the group id.  If the group nature had 5 pictures, then there would be 5 entries in there pointing to nature.
2. Store all the files as an array in the group row.  For example, I'll have a column in the group table to put an array of files.
3. Store the group(s) in the images table.  I would have a column in the images table where I set the group it is in.

Which would be the best choice of action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with the relationships.

- An image can be in one or more groups.
- A group can have one or more images.

So, now we create the domain tables.

```
Image
-----
Image ID
File name
Image size
...

Group
-----
Group ID
Group name
Group description
...
```

Now, we create the junction table

```
GroupImage
----------
Group ID
Image ID
Group image time stamp
...
```

The primary (clustering) key is (Group ID, Image ID).  You would also define a unique index on (Image ID, Group ID).

Basically, you define the relationships, then you can define the relational tables.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new group table with groupid and groups (such as nature, people, etc.) as fields. Then add groupid as a field in the image table. Each image in the image table is assigned the groupid of the group it belongs to from the group table.